# Test cases are executed sucessfully but code is showing RUNTIME error ? The code is given below

Tags: python

problem: You are given two integers N and K. You may perform the following operation any number of times (including zero): change N to N−K, i.e. subtract K from N. Find the smallest non-negative integer value of N you can obtain this way.

```
T=int(input())
for i in range(T):
    N,K=list(map(int,input().split()))
    if N<K:
        print(N)
    else:
        temp=N % K
        print(temp)
```

Test cases are:

```
3
5 2
4 4
2 5
```

tell me why my code is showing runtime error when executed?

Comment: Tell us what the error is, runtime error is too broad. For me your code run successfully without any errors.

Comment: RE (NZEC)
(0.072243)     this is what exactly the compiler is showing

Comment: Is it because the first test case is only one number, when the problem says that N and K will both be given?

Comment: first line is the number of testcases to run,remaining lines are space seperated integers N,K taken as input in a single line

Comment: Assuming `NZEC` is `non zero exit code`, it's still too broad. Post the **full** error message.

Comment: nothing is displayed other than this, RE (NZEC)